# external table gphdfs protocol command ended with error. Error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: greenplum

```
testdb=# CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sales_fact_1997 (                                                                                                                                                                                                    product_id int,                                                                                                                                                                                                                             time_id int,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                customer_id int,                                                                                                                                                                                                                            promotion_id int,                                                                                                                                                                                                                           store_id int,                                                                                                                                                                                                                               store_sales decimal,                                                                                                                                                                                                                        store_cost decimal,                                                                                                                                                                                                                         unit_sales decimal                                                                                                                                                                                                                          )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      LOCATION ('gphdfs://hz-cluster2/user/nrpt/hive-server/foodmart.db/sales_fact_1997')                                                                                                                                                         FORMAT 'TEXT' (DELIMITER ',');
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE

testdb=# 

testdb=# 

testdb=# 

testdb=# select * from sales_fact_1997 ;                                                                                                                                                                                                    
ERROR:  external table gphdfs protocol command ended with error. Error occurred during initialization of VM  (seg0 slice1 sdw1:40000 pid=3450)
DETAIL:  

Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
Command: 'gphdfs://le/user/nrpt/hive-server/foodmart.db/sales_fact_1997'
External table sales_fact_1997, file gphdfs://hz-cluster2/user/nrpt/hive-server/foodmart.db/sales_fact_1997
```

I changed the value of -Xmx from hadoop-2.5.2/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh file and I see the can used memory is enough of JVM. but I still get this error.
as follows

```
@localhost ~]$ free -m
export GP_JAVA_OPT='-Xms20m -Xmx20m -XX:+DisplayVMOutputToStderr'


              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            993         114         393         219         485         518
Swap:           819           0         819
```

who can help me ,I created  EXTERNAL TABLE succeed but I can't read data from hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

You either don't have enough memory on your segment hosts or you need to allocate more memory for the JVM.  Here is how you can configure the JVM for gphdfs:
http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4380/admin_guide/load/topics/g-gphdfs-jvm.html

Comment: thank for your answer ,I changed the GP_JAVA_OPT the xmx is 20M but I still get the error @Jon Roberts

Comment: The default is 1000M so you'll need to increase, not decrease the memory setting.  You will need to make this change to all segment hosts and also make sure you have enough total memory for your segments plus gphdfs.

Comment: I think the reason of error is not enough memory for heap space to initialization  .so I decrease the memory of heap space. I hope the vm can  use less momory to start up. @Jon Roberts